# Add a value with the <select> option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I need to add the value of a variable to the value of the  option.
Option values ​​are redeemed through a spreadsheet in Google Docs.

[PROJECT ONLINE](https://codepen.io/cinthia-danielle/pen/OJbPKar)

[spreadsheet with values](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSQPd-p7bwtcbq5U__fVUpEfalwijNJSIsXQANFW2kDEXwK4i-kjjWDmH-kmRqBgcAxPx0ZflGTZMB3/pubhtml)

I'm using the code below to retrieve the values:

```
 //Add value with fee
    $(document).ready(function() {

   var sheetURL ="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1J0qyxUCCkvcFGZ6EIy9nDOgEuTlpI5ICVG3ZsBd_H-I/1/public/values?alt=json";

   $.getJSON(sheetURL, function(data) {
     var entryData = data.feed.entry;
     console.log(data);
     jQuery.each(entryData, function() {
       $("#totalSumWithFee").append(

         '<option hidden="hidden" selected="selected"  value="default">Choice</option><option value="' + this.gsx$values.$t +  '">' + this.gsx$names.$t + '</option>'
  
       );
     });
   });
  });
```

This part is working. So, I tried to add the following code:

```
   //new code
var valueSelectedFee = $('#totalSumWithFee :selected').val();
var cart = 10;

var cartWithFee = cart + valueSelectedFee;

$('.total-sum').html(cartWithFee.toFixed(2));
```

**But NaN value is returning.** Below is the HTML:

```
  <strong>Total: &nbsp;$ <span class="total-sum"></span></strong>
<br><br>
  <select style="width: 200px;" id="totalSumWithFee"></select>
```

**How could I use the option values ​​without returning the NaN value?**

Comment: I think you have to parse `valueSelectedFee` as a number before the addition. Look for `.parseInt()` or `.parseFloat()`,

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette how could i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Because your initial code sets the first "Choice" option as the "selected" option, whose value is "default" (which is not a number), the line in the second section of code:

```
var cartWithFee = cart + valueSelectedFee;
```

is trying to set "cartWithFee" to 10 + "default", adding a string to a number, which doesn't work. If you change that line to:

```
var cartWithFee = cart + (isNaN(valueSelectedFee) ? 0 : valueSelectedFee);
```

then it will replace any NaN values (like "default") to 0, and should work correctly.